# SQL "ROWS BETWEEN" inputting an expression instead of numerical value

Tags: sql, mysql

I am new to SQL. Is there a way to use the "ROWS BETWEEN" with a not predetermined numerical value?

For example:

```
SUM(price) OVER (ORDER BY id ROWS BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND duration FOLLOWING)
```

This gives a syntax error, as the "duration" here is not a numerical number, but an input in my case, and I don't know its value.
Is there a way to get around this?

Suppose I have a table, and for every row I want to sum up this row and the next two rows under it:

(id, price)

(1, 100.0)

(2, 100.0)

(3, 0.0)

(4, 0.0)

(5, 100.0)

If duration is 3, the results should be something like this:

(1, 200.0)

(2, 100.0)

(3, 100.0)

Note that the duration is not known, so I cannot set a numerical value.

Thanks!

Comment: Explain what you are trying to do with some sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a limited form of expression in a frame start or end.

You can't just use a column name as you have shown.

The rules are documented here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-functions-frames.html

> For *expr* `PRECEDING` (and *expr* `FOLLOWING`), *expr* can be a `?` parameter marker (for use in a prepared statement), a nonnegative numeric literal, or a temporal interval of the form `INTERVAL` *val* *unit*. For `INTERVAL` expressions, *val* specifies nonnegative interval value, and *unit* is a keyword indicating the units in which the value should be interpreted.

So you can't use `duration`, but you can use a query parameter.

Example:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE myproc(IN duration INT)
BEGIN
  SET @sql = '
    select id, sum(price) over (order by id rows between current row and ? following)
    from mytable';
  PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;

  SET @dur = duration;

  EXECUTE stmt USING @dur;

  DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
END
```

---

Re your comment:

Here's a solution that does what I believe you want, using a self-join between common table expressions.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE myproc(IN duration INT)
BEGIN
  WITH cte AS (
    SELECT id, price, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id) AS rownum
    FROM mytable
  ) 
  SELECT c1.id, SUM(c2.price) AS sliding_window_price_total
  FROM cte AS c1 JOIN cte AS c2 
    ON c1.id <= c2.id AND c2.rownum - c1.rownum BETWEEN 0 AND duration
  GROUP BY c1.id;
END//
```

I'm not sure that's exactly what you want. I will give it as an example, and if you need to modify it, I'll leave that to you.

Comment: Is there any other way to sum consecutive n rows, where n is inputted as a parameter to a stored procedure?